# parsing of where clause in phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

I want to know the complete lifecycle of where clause condition in phoenix.
How does the value of where condition get parse from different classes and intermediate value .
Where is exactly the where clause logic and scan object reside in code

Executing command
                 select ID,NAME from "table_name"where salary >= 45678;
                                                             OR
                 select ID,SALARY from "table_name" where name like '%abcd%';
 is their some kind of reference.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can look for WhereCompiler.compile(...) in QueryCompiler.compileSingleFlatQuery() function

usually trace path for normal select query is:-

```
PhoenixStatement.executeQuery() -> ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan() ->
QueryCompiler.compile() -> compileSelect() -> compileSingleQuery()->
compileSingleFlatQuery()
```

Scan is set in a context and moved around from various compilers and Iterators to properly set. You can look for WhereCompiler code where filters are pushed in a scan.